# trying to figure out error while working on Django framework

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am new to Djnago and  getting following error when opening url - 127.0.0.1/hello
could any on eplease help to figure this out..there is some error with module path but how to resolve it.

```
ImportError at /hello
No module named defaults
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello
Django Version: 1.6.2
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    No module named defaults
Exception Location: /home/mkp/Desktop/djcode/mysite/mysite/urls.py in <module>, line 14
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    ['/home/mkp/Desktop/djcode/mysite',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol']
Server time:    Sun, 20 Apr 2014 16:42:25 +0000
```

**urls.py:-**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from mysite.views import hello

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^hello/$', hello),
)
```

**`views.py:-`**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your import statement in `urls.py`. Replace:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
```

with:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
```

Comment: I revised my answer, from `django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url` not work when django version>1.5, django 1.5 both of them work well, `django.conf.urls.defaults` has been removed in Django 1.6, that is, only `django.conf.urls` works